# Login popup for upvoting answer workflow issue

Tags: feature-request, bug, login, post-feedback

**Problem**:

I keep mistakenly trying to Signup when I upvote a post.

When the popup opens to Login or Signup, all I see is the StackExchange box w/ logo and immediately click on this, and fail to see that is says "Sign Up [...]" and not "Log in".

[image: Login/Signup popup]

After being redirected to the Signup/Login page, I correctly login.

Please change this so I can login directly from the popup.

**Problem**:

So after the above successful login (through the signup page and not login link), there is no redirect to the post I initially wanted to upvote. If you click the `log in` link correctly, it will redirect you to the post where you can upvote (or [insert action here]) the post.

I have not tested to see if it will correctly redirect you to the post if you were to Sign Up.